# pdf generation using html-pdf npm package , deploy on AWS as a GET api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pdf, serverless, html-pdf

I am able to generate a pdf using html-pdf in nodejs locally on my mac. The minute I deploy the my GET api using serverless on AWS everything fails. The pdf does not get generated and I get 400 bad request and message as **html-pdf: Received the exit code '127'\n/var/task/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n**

I changed version of the html-pdf package , tried installing fontmanager but nothing helped.

```
//pdf generation class
{
.....
const pdfSettings = {
                "border": '1cm',
                "header": {
                    "height": "15mm"
                }
            };

            const PDFBuffer = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                pdf.create(pdfContent, pdfSettings).toBuffer(
                    (err, buffer) => {
                        err ? reject(err) : resolve(buffer);
                    });
            });

            const buffer = await PDFBuffer;
            return actions.downloadPDF(contactId, buffer);
}

//function which returns pdf in binary to api gateway
downloadPDF(pdfName, pdfBuffer) {

    let responseObj = {
      statusCode: 200,
      isBase64Encoded: true,
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
        'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + pdfName + '.pdf'
      },
      body: pdfBuffer && JSON.stringify(pdfBuffer.toString('base64'))
    }
    return responseObj;
  }
```

I should be able to generate pdf using the GET api in AWS. Please let me know any valuable suggestion that could help me with this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reach a better solution by using puppeteer library. Reasons for choosing a different library

html-pdf is deprecated

puppeteer has much better options

puppeteer has async/await feature

Although to make this work in AWS with serverless & serverless-plugin-optimize , I did face many challenges. Note out the following points while implementing this kind of similar scenario

**For API gateway to send any binary file(pdf / jpeg / jpg) as response**

Binary Media Types should be set to `*/*` in API Gateway resource Settings options , if going through serverless under provider in serverless.yaml add
 **apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
      - `*/*`**

if by any chance you are using serverless-plugin-optimize to reduce lambda size , use "external" option for this package chrome-aws-lambda , ref link https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-optimize

Answer (score 2):

faced the same issue with html-pdf on aws ubuntu and here is what I did.

test html-pdf package using the example:

```
root@APP-AP-1A-01:/home/user01/server-a7# node node_modules/html-pdf/bin/index.js node_modules/html-pdf/examples/businesscard/businesscard.html /tmp/test-prod.pdf
/home/user01/server-a7/node_modules/html-pdf/bin/index.js:30
    if (err) throw err
             ^

Error: html-pdf: Received the exit code '127'
/home/user01/server-a7/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.respond (/home/user01/server-a7/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:121:31)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
```

^  this error was seen on Aws running Ubuntu (4.4.0-1072-aws)
and it was due to missing library phantomjs is dependent on; the `npm -i` did not install/ update it quite well on the server.

Here are the steps:

1. ldd - print shared object dependencies (note that it flagged, libfontconfig.so.1 => not found)
2. install the missing library (apt-get install fontconfig)
3. check the dependencies again using ldd
4. run the example and this time it created the pdf from html

run as root user or use sudo :-

```
root@APP-AP-1A-01:/home/user01/server-a7# ldd /home/user01/server-a7/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffea155d000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd639645000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => not found
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fd63939b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd639197000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd638f8f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd638d72000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd6389f0000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd6386e7000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd6384d1000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd638107000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd63985f000)
        libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fd637ee2000)

root@APP-AP-1A-01:/home/user01/server-a7# ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1': No such file or directory

root@APP-AP-1A-01:/home/user01/server-a7# apt-get install fontconfig
Reading package lists... Done
:
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core libfontconfig1
:
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 fonts-dejavu-core all 2.35-1 [1,039 kB]
Get:2 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 fontconfig-config all 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 [49.9 kB]
Get:3 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libfontconfig1 amd64 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 [131 kB]
Get:4 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 fontconfig amd64 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 [178 kB]
Fetched 1,398 kB in 1s (928 kB/s)
:
:
Regenerating fonts cache... done.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11.2) ...

root@APP-AP-1A-01:/home/user01/server-a7# ldd /home/user01/server-a7/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcdf49c000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f65a4723000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f65a44e0000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f65a4236000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f65a4032000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f65a3e2a000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f65a3c0d000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f65a388b000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f65a3582000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f65a336c000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f65a2fa2000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f65a493d000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f65a2d79000)
        libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f65a2b54000)

root@APP-AP-1A-01:/home/user01/server-a7# node node_modules/html-pdf/bin/index.js node_modules/html-pdf/examples/businesscard/businesscard.html /tmp/test-prod.pdf

root@APP-AP-1A-01:/home/user01/server-a7# ls -lrt /tmp/test-prod.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11250 Jul 10 10:05 /tmp/test-prod.pdf
```

created the pdf in /tmp/test-prod.pdf

Comment: Thanks for posting! you saved my time.

Comment: Wow, thanks!! That's it! `sudo apt-get install fontconfig`